# How to get twitter URL count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter, jsonp

I've got the following code, and I cannot understand as to why it isn't returning and printing it in the HTML body..

```
var pageURL = document.URL;
var tweet  = "https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='"+ pageURL + "'";

$.getJSON(tweet,function(json){
    $('#twitterfeed').html(json.count); 
});

<div id="twitterfeed"></div>
```

https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com

returns {"count":23844636,"url":"http://www.google.com/"}

The following doesn't seem to work, does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: Is the JavaScript before the HTML in the same file?

Comment: Yes, It's on the top.

Comment: Wrap it in $(function(){ // your code here }); which will delay its execution until the DOM has been loaded and parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default jQuery makes AJAX request. Since it's cross domain and CORS HTTP header is not present in response it fails. Add &callback=? to request URL to make JSONP request

```
  var pageURL = "http://www.google.com";
  var urlParams = $.param({ "url": pageURL });
  var tweet  = "https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?"+urlParams;


  $.ajax(tweet, { "dataType" :"jsonp" }).done(function(json){
    $('#twitterfeed').text(json.count); 
  });
```

Demo

http://jsbin.com/tasaloraje/edit?html,output

Comment: It doesn't seem to work though, look at this one.. http://jsbin.com/yebotuwaya/edit?html,output But If you remove the '" + pageURL + "' and include the url it works.. do you have any idea as to why that is?

Comment: Changed script by adding proper URL encoding for page URL, using $.ajax call with deferred (as recommended by jQuery developers). Check jsFiddle

Comment: This is now deprecated (https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform).

Answer (score 10):

As of 20th November 2015 there's no Tweet count API, so don't bother: https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform

Comment: Thanks. According to the end of the blog post, maybe there will be a equivalent in the near future ? Anyway I think it's  a very bad decisions to remove it. Even facebook API has improved this likes count in its API. Hopefully twitter will implement it again in a better way. " We appreciate your feedback over the past 60 days on how you have used these counts, and look forward to incorporating it as we create and improve tools to integrate Twitter content into your apps and websites".

Answer (score 2):

https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json is deprecated.

Check out http://opensharecount.com for a replacement though, you can just change it to the URL mentioned there if you sign up for your domain.

Comment: thanks, nice alternative, however much more slow... :/

Comment: I prefer slow but working over not working ;-)  And it is only counting that goes slow, display should be fast as we are using a CDN.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good alternative, definitely, but limiting somehow: what about getting the number of tweets for a youtube video, when the url belongs to youtue.com or an external domain name ? I really hope twitter will provide an alternative even if we have to pay